# Xamarin Forms Relative Layout trailing spaces

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill">

  <RelativeLayout HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue">

    <Image  x:Name="dishImageView" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Maroon" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="10" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="10" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="80" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="80" Source="pizza1.png" />
    <Label Text="Dominoz Pizza" 
           x:Name="pizzaTitle"
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="10"
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                                              ElementName= dishImageView,
                                                                Constant=20,
        Property=Width,
        Factor=1}"/>


         <Label BackgroundColor="Lime" HeightRequest="60" Margin="0,0,20,0" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="Dominoz Pixxa is great pizza.. come and eat pizza" 
           x:Name="pizzaDescription"
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                                              ElementName=pizzaTitle,
                                                               Constant=10,
           Property= Height, Factor=1}"
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                                              ElementName= dishImageView,
                                                                Constant=20,
        Property=Width,
        Factor=1}" 
               />


</RelativeLayout>  
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Basically I am from iOS background. There we use to have leading and trailing spaces. I am not able to see any trailing space option in Xamarin forms.... Can You Please help me how to set this... Here is the sample image what I am trying to implement.

[image: Desired Output]

And here is What I am able to get with above source code.
[image: Current Output]

Comment: You mean `LineBreakMode` on the `Label`

Comment: Yes something like that... I want to set that there should be always 20 space on right side of description Label. and label should come in 2 lines

Comment: Set `<Label Margin="0,0,20,0" MaxLines="2" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" ... />`

Comment: I added but still its not coming in two lines

Comment: Is there a reason why you have chosen `RelativeLayout` and not `StackLayout`s?

Comment: Not any Specific ... I was just trying to dig more into Relative Layout as I used to use this in iOS and Android...  So is this not possible in Relative Layout what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated my Question.. Now I am setting margin , LineBreakMode everything... Then also its showing in one Line only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [a few blogs](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith%27s-xamarin-forms-performance-tips) around advising to not use `RelativeLayout`, and use `AbsoluteLayout` and/or `StackLayout` instead, for performance reasons. I personally am not a fan of `RelativeLayout` and will try to use alternatives wherever possible. `RelativeLayout` is also not fun to play with, and the code can get messy quickly.

The layout you are trying to achieve can indeed be done using `RelativeLayout`, but I think it'll be much easier to use a series of `StackLayout`s. For example:

```xml
<StackLayout 
    HeightRequest="100" 
    BackgroundColor="Blue"
    Orientation="Horizontal">

    <!-- Image -->
    <Image  
        x:Name="dishImageView" 
        Aspect="AspectFit" 
        BackgroundColor="Maroon" 
        Source="pizza1.png" />

    <!-- Image/Item Description -->
    <StackLayout
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label 
            Text="Dominoz Pizza" 
            x:Name="pizzaTitle"/>

        <Label 
            BackgroundColor="Lime" 
            HeightRequest="60" 
            Margin="0,0,20,0" 
            MaxLines="2" 
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
            Text="Dominoz Pixxa is great pizza.. come and eat pizza" 
            x:Name="pizzaDescription"/>

        <!-- Add the price label here -->

    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

And Here I achieved it Finally using Grid Concept.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="UdemyFirst.PizzaPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>  
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image 
                BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="10"
                Grid.Column="0"/>

            <StackLayout 
                BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>  
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/> 
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/> 
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label 
                        Text="Pizza"
                        BackgroundColor="Black"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        TextColor="White"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="Pizza is very bad. You should not eat Pizza. Pizza is very bad."
                        BackgroundColor="Red"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                        MaxLines="2"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        TextColor="White"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="10$"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        XAlign="End"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        TextColor="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

    </StackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```